# Merge two hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I have 2 hashes with keys and values

```
h1 = {"January"=>1, "February"=>2, "March"=>4, "April"=>5, "May"=>5, "June"=>6}

h2 = {1=>3, 2=>5, 3=>10, 4=>12, 6=>14}
```

And I am expecting have a result like

```
result = {3=>1, 5=>2, 10=>4, 12=>5, 14=>6}
```

I tried this solution

> If you want 1 to return both "first" and "one", you'll need to store
>   them in an array which will then be the value of which 1 maps to.

```
results = {}

  hash1.each do |key, value|   if results[key].nil?
     results[key] = [value]   else
     results[key] << value

hash2.each do |key, value|   if results[key].nil?
     results[key] = [value]   else
     results[key] << value

results[1]
# => ["one", "first"]
```

But my result is

```
{1=>[3], 2=>[5], 3=>[10], 4=>[12], 6=>[14], "January"=>[1], "February"=>[2], "March"=>[4], "April"=>[5], "May"=>[5], "June"=>[6]}
```

Comment: seems like the last key-val in the expected result should be 14-5 right?

Comment: wako, finally I came up with a solution thank to @maxpleaner , could you see if that's what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i looking for have a result hash with the values of my first hash and my second hash not with months like values, to give more details my first hash values are numbers of sales per month and in the second the price range per month

Comment: At the end i want do something like 3/1, 5/2, 10/4, 12/5, 14/6 and display all this result in line chart group_by month

Comment: @Wako ok, see my edited answer, at the end I added a new info you could use to do that

Comment: Examples are generally helpful for clarifying questions, but they are not a substitute for stating the question in words (precisely). For each pair `k,v` in `h2`, it appears you want `result` to contain `v=>k` if `h1` has a value equal to `k`, but that does not hold with `4=>12` and I don't see how `3=>10` is transformed to `10=>4`. Please clarify with an edit.

Comment: Thank you so much its what i looking for !

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are sorround it in a list, try do the followin, don't need to do the second foreach loop:

> Recomended way:

```
hash1 = {"January"=>1, "February"=>2, "March"=>4, "April"=>5, "May"=>5, "June"=>6}

hash2 = {1=>3, 2=>5, 3=>10, 4=>12, 6=>14}

results = {}

#here you have to swap key-value for value-key

hash2.each do |value, key| 
  if results[key].nil?
    results[key] = value
  else 
    results[key] << value
  end
end

results
```

> => {3=>1, 5=>2, 10=>3, 12=>4, 14=>6}
>
> Alternative way:

You can zip the two lists, one of keys, another of values, and then put them in a dictionary:

```
hash1 = {"January"=>1, "February"=>2, "March"=>4, "April"=>5, "May"=>5, "June"=>6}

hash2 = {1=>3, 2=>5, 3=>10, 4=>12, 6=>14}

results = {}

(hash2.values).zip(hash1.values).each do |key, value| 
  if results[key].nil?
    results[key] = value
  else 
    results[key] << value
  end
end

results
```

> => {3=>1, 5=>2, 10=>4, 12=>5, 14=>5}

Comment: look at the expected output in the question, this is not the same